# Source code of SNMPv3 in C in linux platform

Tags: net-snmp

where can I get Net SNMP libraries and tools link?

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem?

This is the [**home page for Net-SNMP**](http://www.net-snmp.org/).  [Page to download tools and source codes](http://www.net-snmp.org/download.html) and its open-source code under GNU licence. You can compile your own and install. If you want you can modify code too. And [here is the library documentation](http://www.net-snmp.org/dev/agent/group__library.html). And the [SNMPv3 details are here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2571.txt).